# REGEX for defining path in rails backend and angular2 frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, angular2-routing

I am using Rails backend and angular2 frontend. I have defined path as this but it is showing error in path.

```
 path_regex: '\A/post/user/(.*)\z'
```

But I want regex for this path:

```
 post/user?description=abbb&name=qqqq&service=auth
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking to include `description`, `name`, and `service=auth`, how about

```
^post\/user\?description=(.+)&name=(.+)&service=auth$
```

Comment: I am using this in frontend
`post/user?description=${post.description}&name=${post.name}&service=auth`
So, I don't want to write name and description in regex.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what the problem is. Are you using this regex to make sure valid path names are being passed?